# Nanovolts to millivolts signal amplification

Tags: operational-amplifier, energy-harvesting

I need to amplify a weak signal (a few nanovolts) from solenoid to a few hundred millivolts. I am working on an energy harvesting device but I am unsure of the output since the DAQ (HP 34970 A) works in range of millivolts. Is there any amplifier which I can use for this purpose? I had read a few suggestions about using op amp 741 and op amp LT1028.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly why you want to amplify the signal? Also read [on topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and edit your question to avoid it being closed.

Comment: No, you don't, or not unless much ado: this is extremely hard, and usually only possible when you know a lot about the signal you want to amplify, because noise voltages will probably be significantly higher than nV. So, describe your overall problem instead of what you think solves it. Designing a low noise, high gain amplifier is way harder than you might think, and you'll have to restrict what you're amplifying to even make it theoretically possible!

Comment: Also, at nV, we're getting dangerously close to regions where physics starts to get strange, so I'm almost certain that either you're an experimental physicist with an expensive problem, or chasing ghosts. Either way, I'll have to vote to close this question unless you clarify the overall purpose, and what your solenoid is picking up.

Comment: Do you want to amplify a signal, or are you harvesting nV but need mV for your IC?

Comment: @PlasmaHH op does mention a DAQ...

Comment: The LT1028 is profoundly better than the ancient 741 op-amp. You may need two stages to amplify 1,000 times. Without details any more would be just guessing.

Comment: Sparky, it's far from that simple. The lt1028 has 10 uV of offset voltage. That's ten thousand times more than op's signal voltage.

Comment: If you are harvesting energy, then an amplifier won't help.  An amplifier has to draw power from somewhere else.  If you could use an amplifier to get more power without having to provide power the amplifier then you would have a perpetual motion machine.  And hobbyists and engineers would have been building them since forever.

Comment: We need to know a lot more about the characteristics of the signal.  What frequency range?  What is the nature and meaning of the signal you are trying to amplify?  What does it mean for a signal to come from a solenoid? Huh? what?  How is energy harvesting relevant to amplifying this signal? This question is *unclear* in its current form.

Comment: A few nanovolts is lost in noise and thermal EMFs with the kind of circuitry and methods people talk about on this site (i.e. not physics experiments with cryogenics etc.). Forget about it. A 1K resistor at room temperature has 130nV of noise over a 1kHz bandwidth.

Comment: @ronak figure out the noise and bandwidth you require, then go about selecting an amplifier. If your not careful a low noise amplifier with out correct band-limiting will turn in to a much nosier measurement. Do some research edit your question with more information.

Comment: Lets measure some interference from power line wiring inside the building walls, coupling into a loop of the circuit. Using Vinduce = MU0 * MUr * Area/Distance * dI/dT, let I be 1 amp at 60Hz, with dI/dT being 377 amps/second. Let the loop area be (1cm)^2. Let distance from wire to loop be 4" or 0.1 meter. What is Vinduce? Vinduce = 2e-7 * Area/Distance * dI/dT = 2e-7 * 0.0001/0.1 * 377  or 2e-7 * 1e-3 * 377 = 754 * 1e-10 or 75 nanoVolts. And this level of interference is common with RIAA response curves for vinyl-record playback. Placing RTN wire near HOT wire gives 10:1 drop, to 7.5 nanoV.

Comment: Thus moving-coil cartridges, at moderate recording levels with 10uV output levels, will face 7.5nV hum at 60Hz, and the system will have only 63dB SNR or SINAD. Thus nanoVolts are very common, even broadband nanoVolts. Cables, shielding, GNDs tied to other GNDS to capture 60Hz entering by primary to secondary transformer coupling of unbalanced windings, make quality high SNR a challenge.

Comment: The RIAA curve is flat from DC to 50Hz, then one-pole rolloff to 500Hz, flat to 2,000Hz, then a new pole enters. There is lots of discussion of what to attempt below 10Hz where turntable bearing rumble, motor pole cogging, and drive belt flat spots all contribute base energy. And there is lots of discussion of what to attempt above 10Khz or 20KHz, given the uncertainly of what the record-cutting houses laid down on master cutting. Note 3dB bandwidth is only 50Hz. With 6 ohm Rnoise in MC cartridge, or 0.31 nVms noise/rtHz, a 50Hz BW produces 0.31 * sqrt(50) = 0.31 * 7 = 2.1 nanoVolt RMS noise

Answer (score 5):

> I need to amplify a weak signal (a few nanovlts) from solenoid to a few hundred millivolts.

You are chasing at shadows. There is probably no signal there at all.

Nanovolts (10<sup>-9</sup> V) are *ridiculously* small units. There are numerous sources of experimental error which can produce voltages in even the µV range, including:

- Thermal noise.
- Current induced in your test leads by nearby devices (e.g, a cell phone, a computer, fluorescent lighting, or the measuring instrument itself).
- Electrochemical potentials created by differences in metal composition between your test leads and probes, the jacks in the measuring instrument, and/or the devices they are probing.

No amount of energy harvesting can turn a nanovolt potential into useful energy. An amplifier is certainly not helpful, as it requires an electrical input to perform amplification.